# Can't get table borders to be invisible in html

Tags: html, frontpage

I need help to make table borders invisible. Already read some other answers to similar questions, but I wasn't able to solve the problem.

This is the code generated by Frontpage 2003:

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>FOCCoF</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#666666"> <center>

<table border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolorlight="#000000" bordercolordark="#000000" width="991" height="496">
 <!-- MSTableType="layout" -->
 <tr>
  <td height="360" width="981" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">
  <p align="justify">
  <img border="0" src="gendat/banner.gif" width="981" height="114"></p>
  <p align="justify">
  <span style="vertical-align: middle">
  <font face="Lucida Console" size="2"><b>
  <span style="background-color: #FF0000">&nbsp;&nbsp; [</span></b><span style="background-color: #FF0000"><a style="color: #000000" href="index.htm"><u>Inicio</u></a><b>] 
  - [</b><a style="color: #000000" href="p1/p1.htm"><u>Lineamientos</u></a><b>] 
  - [</b><u><a style="color: #000000" href="p2/p2.htm">Comunicados</a></u><b>] 
  - [</b><u><a style="color: #000000" href="p3/p3.htm">Documentos</a></u><b>] 
  - [</b><u><a style="color: #000000" href="p4/p4.htm">Agenda 
  Antirrepresiva</a></u><b>] - [</b><u><a style="color: #000000" href="p5/p5.htm">Biblioteca</a></u><b>] 
  - [</b><a style="color: #000000" href="p6/p6.htm">Multimedia</a><b>]</b></span><b><span style="background-color: #FF0000">&nbsp;<img border="0" src="gendat/fill.gif" width="17" height="10"></span></b></font></span></p>
  <p align="center">
  <img border="0" src="gendat/foccof.gif" width="530" height="200"></p>
  <p align="justify">
  <font face="Lucida Console" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">El FOCCoF, Frente 
  Organizado contra el Código de Faltas, es un frente de organizaciones y 
  compañerxs no agrupadxs que surge allá por el 2012 como una herramienta 
  para enfrentar el intento de reforma del Código de Faltas que quería 
  impulsar el gobierno provincial, presidido por Unión por Córdoba. Si 
  bien en ese momento el frente nos aglutinaba bajo esa coyuntura 
  específica, y con un arco amplio de organizaciones del campo popular, 
  con el correr del tiempo el avance represivo tanto a nivel provincial 
  como nacional fueron modificando nuestros objetivos y estrategias de 
  lucha, para llegar a lo que somos hoy.</font></p>
  <p align="justify"><font face="Lucida Console" color="#FFFFFF" size="2">
  Actualmente al FOCCoF lo vamos construyendo La Brújula Barrial, 
  Cogollos, el Encuentro de Organizaciones, Cauce en COB La Brecha y Ammar, 
  junto con compañerxs no agrupadxs. Siempre abierto a todxs aquellas 
  organizaciones y personas que se quieran sumar a esta lucha que damos 
  día a día para frenar el avance represivo que vivimos en nuestra 
  actualidad.</font></p>
  <p align="justify">
  &nbsp;</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p align="justify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span style="background-color: #666666">&nbsp;</span><font face="Lucida Console"><b><font size="2"><span style="background-color: #FF0000">[</span></font></b><span style="background-color: #FF0000"><font size="2"><a style="color: #000000" href="py/py.htm"><u>Links</u></a></font><b><font size="2">]</font></b></span></font><span style="background-color: #666666">
</span><font face="Lucida Console"><b><font size="2">
<span style="background-color: #666666">&nbsp;</span></font></b></font><span style="background-color: #666666">
</span><span style="vertical-align: middle; background-color:#FF0000">
  <font face="Lucida Console" size="2"><b>[</b><a style="color: #000000" href="px/px.htm"><u>Contacto</u></a></font></span><span style="vertical-align: middle"><font face="Lucida Console" size="2"><b><span style="background-color: #FF0000">]</span></b></font></span><span style="background-color: #666666">
</span></p>

</center>

<p align="justify">&nbsp;</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what borders? You've got `border="0"`, which turns them off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But.. If you mean the white 'border', this isn't a border. It's the backgroundcolor of the table.

Just change the table element to:

```
<table width="991" height="496">
```

Let me know if this worked out for you.